# Common header view on top of nib files with Interface builder

Tags: iphone, uiview, interface-builder

.Hi,

I have a nib file that contains an header that will be used in most of my views, so that I can change it's layout just once when I need. I'd like to know if it's possible to add the header nib view with interface builder, or if I need to do that programmatically and how should it be done.

I've thought about setting the subclass of the subview to a UIView subclass that automatically loads the nib file.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    UIView *cell;

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"MainHeaderView"
                                                 owner: self
                                               options: nil];

    for (id oneObject in nib) 
        if ([oneObject isKindOfClass: [UIView class]]) 
            cell = (UIView *) oneObject;

    if ((self = [super initWithFrame: [cell frame]])) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

But this also doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've solved this another way.

I've created the headerView and the controller, and a subclass of UIViewController for all views that needed the header to be displayed, loading them all with the header. Something like this:

```
@implementation MyDefaultViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyTestAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [self.view addSubview: [appDelegate.headerViewController view]];
}
```

Every view that needs the header to be there will have a controller that's a subclass of MyDefaultViewController. Seems to work, although the fact that I don't specify where to place the header scares me a bit xD

Answer (score 0):

It should work, at least in theory.  For that matter, it should be possible (but with rather a lot of effort) to add it via IB, from what used to be called a palette, a long time ago; I believe that option was recreated.

I would say that loading from `initWithFrame:` is likely not to work.  Other possible places to load would be `awakeFromNib` (with a caveat about multiple nib loadings causing it to be called multiple times), or `viewDidLoad`.  Try moving the load to `viewDidLoad`, and see if your `cell` is connected up.  You should also be testing for failure to load the nib (`nil` return).